# Plotting an image next to a ruler using r

Tags: r

What I would like to do is make a series of plots that combine an image with a scale that is related to the height of the image, but is multiplied by a factor.

So far I've been able to make a plot using the following code:

```
    library(imager)
    im <- load.image("ZAB17_4.png")
    plot(im)
```

[Image is attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x5e9.png)

[image]

But what I would like to do is to have the y-axis be scaled by a value:

```
    pixel_size <- 0.0596
```

I would also get rid of the x-axis. (xaxt="n" doesn't seem to do the trick). Ideally, I would like the Y-axis to be directly adjacent to the image. I've been trying to poke around with scales in the plot function, but haven't found what I need to do this, but I'm sure there is a simple solution.

*Edited to add image. I should note that the goal is really just to add a scale to the image. The pixel size represents the size of each pixel in reality in mm. I basically want to add a ruler along the side of the image. Maybe r is not the best tool for this, but I plan to also plot data taken from the imaged object and plot it alongside.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please create a reproducible example by providing the image file you used to make this graph.

Comment: I have added the image and some further explanation

Comment: Normally I would expect `xaxs = 'i', yaxs = 'i'` to force the axes to stop exactly at the limits, but it's not seeming to work here... But if by "have the y-axis be scaled by 0.0596" you mean that you want the vertical dimension compressed, set `asp = 0.0596` and at least that part works.

Comment: For the axis, I would recommend setting `axes = FALSE` in your `plot` command and then add the y-axis directly in a new command, `axis(side = 2)` (with additional configuration as need, see `?axis`).